# How to recreate the IPN from PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We had an error in one of our scripts and even if the notify_url from PayPal was called properly, our system was not able to record it since it had errors.

Therefore we have several transactions in PayPal that were not added to our Data Base, is there any way to recreate PayPal's IPN or re-execute the notify_url for each transaction?

Thanks!

FYI: we are using Website Payments Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your PayPal profile, then into Instant Payment Notification Preferences.  You'll see a link there for IPN history.  You can see all of the IPN's that have been sent by PayPal to your system and their status.  You can select IPN's from this history list resend them as needed so your system can process them accordingly.

Comment: It might have changed but the way to get there now is like this: Go into your PayPal profile, on the menu into History --> IPN history.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the version of PayPal you have.  Sometimes the drop down over History works, sometimes it doesn't.  I was thinking the profile method would always be there regardless of whether or not your drop down worked, so that's why I mentioned that method, but if you didn't see it there I guess you'll get one or the other.  Glad you were able to find it.